# Scala Play framework 'update' json array

Tags: json, scala, parsing, playframework-2.0

Suppose I have a json array that looks like this (I receive it from a remote service):

```
[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, ... , {"id": 10}]
```

And, say, I want to 'transform' it like this (add 100 to 'id's and other values):

```
[{"id": 101}, {"id": 102}, ..., {"id": 110} ]
```

As for starters I wanted to 'update' it so that it would at least replace the initial array with a blank one (just to test how stuff works).

```
Json.parse("""[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]""").transform( (__).json.update( __.read[JsArray].map(_ => JsArray()) ))
```

But it throws an exception:

```
play.api.libs.json.JsResult[play.api.libs.json.JsObject] = JsError(List((,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsobject),WrappedArray())))))
```

However if they are sealed inside of a json object then it kinda works:

```
Json.parse("""{"ids": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]}""").transform( (__ \ "ids").json.update( __.read[JsArray].map(_ => JsArray()) ))
```

which results in

```
play.api.libs.json.JsResult[play.api.libs.json.JsObject] = JsSuccess({"ids":[]},/ids)
```

How do I deal with array json? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code,

```
case class ID(id: Int)
implicit val reads = Json.reads[ID]

Json.parse("""[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]""").as[JsArray].value.map(_.transform(__.json.update {
  __.read[ID].map { case x: ID => Json.obj("id" -> (x.id + 100)) }
}))
```

Comment: Thanks!
But what if I want to output it to the user's browser?
It seems that I cannot just pass it to "Ok(...)" as it is not "Writable".

Comment: Why not ask this as a separate question?

Comment: Seems reasonable! Thank you for your help.